# Plugin doesn't support this project's apple-xcode version

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, ionic2

My google map plugin for ios project is not working
get error while trying install map plugin on ios

`Plugin doesn't support this project's apple-xcode version. apple-xcode: 8.3.2, failed version requirement: >=9.0.0`

how can install map plugin without update xcode version

Help me to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Well,first remove the ios platform

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
```

Edit the file **~/your-app-name/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/plugin.xml**,  with your version xcode

```
<engines>
    <engine name="apple-xcode" version=">=[YOUR_VERSION]" />
</engines>
```

In this case YOUR_VERSION is 8.3.2